# How to add a filter for Apache axis SOAP web service

Tags: java, web-services, soap, axis

I have developed soap web service using apache axis and deployed it on tomcat.
Now I want to restrict access to my web service to some specific IP's. I tried adding a servlet filter and checked for IP from request but I am not able to throw or retun SOAPFault message from that filter.

So my requirement is if incoming IP is not the trusted one throw SOAP exception i,e return a XML with error details.

Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

The SOAPException when thrown from the context of the Axis framework will generate a SOAPFault. When you are in a filter you are not in an Axis framework context. So the simplest thing you can do is send a code built SOAP fault in the response.